# Why was this Onslaught toy sold as Red Skull?

Tags: marvel, toys, merchandise

I'm wondering if Red Skull has ever appeared in a form similar to Onslaught's, in the comics or video games. Essentially, any media other than this toy:

[image: Marvel Legends Red Skull Build-A-Figure] [image]

If so, that answers my question.

But if not, I'm trying to figure out why this figure was ever marketed as Red Skull. I've a hunch that maybe the rights to Onslaught weren't clear at the time (perhaps because of the *Marvel vs. Capcom* video game?).

In a later toy wave, a different figure almost randomly included an Onslaught head, which is interchangeable with the Red Skull to form a complete Onslaught:

[image: Marvel Legends Kitty Pryde] [image: Marvel Legends Onslaught Build-A-Figure]

However, this head was included with no explanation (no mention on the box) and none of the materials anywhere seem to officially call the figure Onslaught, still. Despite the fact it's *clearly* Onslaught:

[image: Marvel's Onslaught]

So, what gives? Did Red Skull ever wear armor like this? Did Hasbro just not have rights to make toys of Onslaught because someone else does, so they couldn't officially make an Onslaught figure? If so, any idea who *does* have the license to make Onslaught figures?

For reference, this figure was revealed in late 2015 and hit retail early 2016.

Comment: What is that flesh-colored, veiny thing in the box with Kitty Pryde (I know nothing about comics, sorry if it's obvious)?

Comment: Looks like an arm,@OrganicMarble

Comment: @OrganicMarble [It's Juggernaut's arm for another Build-A-Figure.](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/mh3h9bttP7U/maxresdefault.jpg)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## This is Red Onslaught from the 616 comic continuity

in *Uncanny Avengers #2* [A Red Skull Clone](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Johann_Shmidt_(Clone)_(Earth-616)) stole the brain of the Professor X and grafted part it to his own so he could have his powers.

Then in the build up to *Avengers & X-Men: AXIS* Magneto kills this Red Skull, in ***Uncanny Avengers #25***, by smashing his head in with a brick (not using his powers), this was in part due to Red Skull turning Genosha into a concentration camp.

However this creates Red Onslaught, and Avengers & X-Men: AXIS deals with attempting to stop him

This is a cover of AXIS #1
[image: AXIS #1 Cover]

As he becomes able to use more of his powers his appearance seems to change, growing tentacles and horns.

[image: Red Onslaught AXIS #1]

---

### Why is the toy called Red Skull and not Red Onslaught?

I cannot find anything specific about this toy, but, this [Forbes article](https://www.forbes.com/sites/davegonzales/2015/05/31/marvel-is-killing-x-men-and-fantastic-four-merchandising/#524eae9d2b51) from 2015 suggests that Marvel isn't / wasn't pushing any merchandising for characters that they do not own the movie rights to. This is due to them getting less than 5% of the money from them.

> *"...Marvel Executive Editor Tom Brevoort responded to a question on Tumblr about the lack of X-Men toys: “If you had two things, and on one you earned 100% of the revenues from the efforts that you put into making it, and the other you earned a much smaller percentage for the same amount of time and effort, you’d be more likely to concentrate more heavily on the first, wouldn’t you?”*

Marvel do not [own the Onslaught name](http://www.popculthq.com/2016/02/12/marvel-comic-characters-which-movie-studios-own-who/), so they may have taken the decision to avoid any legal challenges over partial usage of the name, such as they were threatened with over Wonder Man, and just stuck with a name they owned fully and could get 100% of the money from.

Comment: That's pretty close, but the horns there are very different. Hmm.

Comment: @CreationEdge he appears to change through the comics, he gets tentacles too, have added the cover art of AXIS#1 that shows him sans horns

Comment: Ah, yeah, I just found some more images, too. That's definitely him. I still wonder why they call him "Red Skull" and not "Red Onslaught".

Comment: @CreationEdge maybe they thought Red Skull is more well know and would appeal more to the mainstream fans that hadn't read this comic-line? I love marvel ad this was the first I'd heard of him tbh. im sure my son would know all about him if i asked though

Comment: I can't tell if that cover says AXIS, FIXIS or SIXIS.

Comment: Its supposed to read the same upside down - looks like SIXIS to me too

Comment: @Petersaber It says AXIS and reads the same if you flip it 180 degrees ;)

Comment: Huh. Well, Red Skull is widely known, but the Marvel Legends characters aren't always. And they've done "Iron Skull". If it helps, this figure was announced in late 2015.

Comment: @CearonO'Flynn let's just say it's not a very well designed ambigram :P

Comment: Fox owning the rights to the characters could be an interesting part of this (but, at the same time, X-Men characters were being made and released the same year, including the Onslaught head Kitty Pryde.) AFAIK, licensing deals to toy manufacturers are separate from deals for movie rights, so Hasbro could still have had license to all sorts of properties. Hmm. Could also just have been a marketing gaff, someone not knowing enough when they made the box.

Comment: Ah but with Kitty Pryde that's 1 toy you take a hit with. Having onslaught on 6 toy's, one of which is Cap, could be more financially damaging. All just guesses anyway as can't find any other reasons for name change.

Comment: Given that in Kitty Pride box there is a part of another toy other than Onslaught, and that the toys line is called "Build a figure" , I have a totally different theory: parts were voluntarily scattered across different boxes so to "force" kids to buy many of them to be able to build the character the right way. More or less the same than publishing a big saga on different comics of different characters, so to force readers to buy 15 issues each month to be able to understand what's going on.

Comment: @motoDrizzt, oh thats a given with the build-a-figure's. You had to collect Cap, Scourge, Taskmaster, Whirlwind, Sharon Carter and Mockingbird to get the Red Onslaught figure. I think the later X-men line came about from fan demand, so the Magneto head could be used to make the original Onslaught as the only other Onslaught figure was a pre-finalised one.

Comment: Right. Fans wanted an Onslaught head so it was announced. Actually, originally slotted as part of Rogue's box but moved to Kitty for final retail. But I brought Kitty up specifically because Marvel doesn't have movie rights to any X-Men, but Hasbro did X-Men Marvel Legends, so I don't think it had to do with movie ownership is all.